# ld: framework not found Crashlytics Xcode7.2.1

Tags: swift, cocoapods, crashlytics

I installed Fabric using CocoaPods.
My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target '*****' do
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
end
target '****Tests' do
end
target '****UITests' do
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
    configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
  end
end
```

Add a Run Script Build Phase

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" ****
```

Build Settings - Enable Bitcode - NO

I did Clean and Build 
But I have mistake 
ld: framework not found Crashlytics
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Can you check what the `Framework Search Paths` setting is? In the **Build Settings** of your target.

Comment: "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleMaps/Frameworks" $(PROJECT_DIR)

Comment: try add `$(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Crashlytics/iOS" "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/iOS"` to the list?

Comment: Now I have mistake ld: framework not found Alamofire. What happened to Xcode?? Before this all worked fine

Comment: Don't worry. I know pretty much what the problem is.

Comment: Also, recommend to have a look at [this](http://www.jontolof.com/cocoa/using-xcconfig-files-for-you-xcode-project/). A bit long but definitely worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your project, you can see a folder called `Pods` right? There you can find a bunch of `xcconfig` files. You'll have to link them to your project's configurations.

See the image below:
[image]

Get rid of the extra paths I told you to add to the `Framework search paths` (sorry :P). And set the configuration files like this.